# Looking for a secure project management platform for our group to use

Tags: project-management, privacy

Our group is a non-profit (most of us are volunteers) with a limited budget doing community awareness on the topic of safe technology use to support health and safety.

We are looking for a project management platform that is safe, secure (data encrypted?), and has a good track record of not having any past security breaches. We need the platform to organize our meetings and activities, as well as facilitate our information and document sharing.

We are looking for project management platform options that have measures in place that would make it difficult, if not impossible, for others to steal information/documents and/or take note of what we are doing/sharing.

Any suggestions on where to look?

Also: What security features should we look for when selecting a project management platform?

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts to share on this question? Any insights are greatly appreciated. Also, I have come across three platforms that we are considering: Basecamp, Trello, and Asana. Could any one of these serve our purposes as a secure, secure platform? Also, any thoughts on the safe and secure nature of Telegram?

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee security - although I have zero reason to doubt it - but I ***strongly*** recommend [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/). [Security](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Security.html) is what they say about security.

It's from JetBrains, and, if you are a coder then you have almost certainly heard of their excellent IDEs, for multiple languages. Given the quality of their IDEs, I have no reason to doubt the security of YouTrack.

It is full-featured, and free if you self host, which I do. Take a look at the the features [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/).

Failing that, those which @user69504 mentioned may well offer free with a limit on either number of projects or number of people. I used [Asana](https://asana.com/) for one project, before I discovered YouTrack. I prefer YouTrack, but Asana did get the job done, as will Basecamp& Trello, plus [many more](https://clickup.com/blog/free-project-management-software/).

You may wish to update our question to say whether you want to self-host on your own server, or want the platform to provide hosting.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I appreciate it! P.S. We wish to find a platform that provides hosting rather than for us to self-hose on our own server.

Comment: I see that you are new around here, and I really want to help. So, please believe that I mean no offence, only advice, when I say that that is is pretty important, and belongs in the question, please edit it (also, please either say that that the hosting must be free, or state a budget). The more information that you give us, the more we can help you. I can tell you from personal experience that Asana provides [both free and paid hosting](https://asana.com/pricing). The limitations on free hosting are quite generous : up to 15 users and 1,000 tasks. Beyond that, it is not terribly expensive

Comment: An alternative might be to find free hosting and use [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/features/). I know that you say that you don't ant to use your own server, but if that is only because of the cost, or the hassle of setting it up, then free hosting + YouTrack is a viable solution (if not, could you satisfy my curiosity & tell us why you don't want to self host? It's more info, which might mean more help from us :-) Let's hope that we can find you a good solution